# Posicionar footer debajo de la caja más alta

Tags: html, css

Tengo dos cajas que distribuyen el contenido verticalmente. Cuando la página cargue no se cual de las dos cajas será más alta ni su tamaño. El footer se debe colocar siempre debajo, con un margen mínimo respecto a la caja más alta (actualmente se me superpone). Irá en la parte inferior de la página si la altura de ambas cajas no da para que el footer se desplaze hacia la parte inferior (el footer no debe quedarse en media de la pantalla, por ejemplo).

Es decir, que la distribución debería quedar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo:

```css
        /*** reset ***/
        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            -moz-box-sizing         : border-box;
            -ms-text-size-adjust    : 100%;
            -webkit-box-sizing      : border-box;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            box-sizing              : border-box;
            font-weight             : normal;
            line-height             : 1em;
            margin                  : 0;
            padding                 : 0;
        }
        html {
            height: 100%;
            position  : relative;
        }
        body {
            background: pink;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }

        article,
        footer,
        header,
        nav {
            background: lightgrey;
            padding   : 1%;
        }
        article,
        footer {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        article {
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        footer {
            border-top: 2px solid grey;
            bottom    : 0;
            height    : 40px;
            left      : 0;
            position  : relative;
            width     : 100%;
        }
        header {
            border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
            height       : 50px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        nav {
            width: 200px;
        }
        section {
            background: lightblue;
            margin-left: 250px;
            padding-right: 50px;
            position    : absolute;
            right       : 0;
            top         : 50px;
            z-index     : -1;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem, adipisci praesentium esse eum! Dolor voluptatibus mollitia quis, iusto quos amet dolores! Vel nihil laboriosam, saepe fugiat sed repellat asperiores deleniti.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit laboriosam nam, quaerat, tempore, esse optio cumque officiis quidem a maiores similique modi. Adipisci sit veritatis optio minima explicabo temporibus nisi!</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis odio, beatae, eligendi neque consectetur impedit quos molestiae, error veritatis omnis, rem maiores aut vero qui. Repudiandae voluptate a, ad perferendis.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, blanditiis quidem placeat suscipit libero, vel iusto enim ratione reiciendis, exercitationem dolor optio tempora ipsam quibusdam rem veritatis ipsa quisquam iure?</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis odio, beatae, eligendi neque consectetur impedit quos molestiae, error veritatis omnis, rem maiores aut vero qui. Repudiandae voluptate a, ad perferendis.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, blanditiis quidem placeat suscipit libero, vel iusto enim ratione reiciendis, exercitationem dolor optio tempora ipsam quibusdam rem veritatis ipsa quisquam iure?</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis odio, beatae, eligendi neque consectetur impedit quos molestiae, error veritatis omnis, rem maiores aut vero qui. Repudiandae voluptate a, ad perferendis.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, blanditiis quidem placeat suscipit libero, vel iusto enim ratione reiciendis, exercitationem dolor optio tempora ipsam quibusdam rem veritatis ipsa quisquam iure?</p>
        </article>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <p style="text-align: center">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías flotar a nav y section a la izquierda, estableciendo sus anchos en porcentajes y finalmente, indicas que no quieres que a footer lo rodee ningún elemento con clear:both

```css
         /*** reset ***/
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        -moz-box-sizing         : border-box;
        -ms-text-size-adjust    : 100%;
        -webkit-box-sizing      : border-box;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        box-sizing              : border-box;
        font-weight             : normal;
        line-height             : 1em;
        margin                  : 0;
        padding                 : 0;
    }
    html {
        height: 100%;
        position  : relative;
    }
    body {
        background: pink;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }


  
    article,
    footer,
    header,
    nav {
        background: lightgrey;
        padding   : 1%;
    }
    article,
    footer {
        margin-top: 20px;
      
    }


    article {
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    footer {
        clear:both;
        border-top: 2px solid grey;
        width: 100%;
        margin:auto;
        margin-top:20px;
        background:yellow;
    }

    header {
        border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
        height       : 50px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    nav {
        float:left;
        width: 20%;
      background-color:red;
    }
    section {
        float:left;
        background: blue;
        width: 80%;
    }
   .container{
     overflow:hidden;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    </header>
    
    <div class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem, adipisci praesentium esse eum! Dolor voluptatibus mollitia quis, iusto quos amet dolores! Vel nihil laboriosam, saepe fugiat sed repellat asperiores deleniti.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit laboriosam nam, quaerat, tempore, esse optio cumque officiis quidem a maiores similique modi. Adipisci sit veritatis optio minima explicabo temporibus nisi!</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis odio, beatae, eligendi neque consectetur impedit quos molestiae, error veritatis omnis, rem maiores aut vero qui. Repudiandae voluptate a, ad perferendis.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, blanditiis quidem placeat suscipit libero, vel iusto enim ratione reiciendis, exercitationem dolor optio tempora ipsam quibusdam rem veritatis ipsa quisquam iure?</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis odio, beatae, eligendi neque consectetur impedit quos molestiae, error veritatis omnis, rem maiores aut vero qui. Repudiandae voluptate a, ad perferendis.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, blanditiis quidem placeat suscipit libero, vel iusto enim ratione reiciendis, exercitationem dolor optio tempora ipsam quibusdam rem veritatis ipsa quisquam iure?</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis odio, beatae, eligendi neque consectetur impedit quos molestiae, error veritatis omnis, rem maiores aut vero qui. Repudiandae voluptate a, ad perferendis.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, blanditiis quidem placeat suscipit libero, vel iusto enim ratione reiciendis, exercitationem dolor optio tempora ipsam quibusdam rem veritatis ipsa quisquam iure?</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p style="text-align: center">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu solución se aproxima bastante. Ya había pensado hacerlo con floats.
Para corregir tu solución: quitar el `margin-top` del primer `article`. El `clear:both` hay que aplicarlo a un elemento anterior al `footer` para que su margen superior tenga efecto. Y se eliminan los estilos de `body` y `html`. 
Aplicar 15% de `width` para el `nav`, 80% para el `section` y un `margin-left`: 5% también para este. Saludos.

Comment: Claro, con eso creo que quedaría tal cual lo solicitaste. Saludos.

Comment: Vale, faltaría bajar el `footer`. Si no le das una altura mínima suficiente a una de las dos cajas "para que lo baje" en algunas pantallas va a quedar en posiciones extrañas.

Comment: Acabo de editarla, agregué un div de contenedor para nav y section, al cuál le settee overflow:hidden. Al parecer eso arregla el comportamiento extraño de footer que no reconoce margin-top.

Comment: @Orici recuerda apoyar dando votos a respuestas que han sido útiles. Saludos.